# Figura Modernista con CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

'Estoy tratando de hacer un forma concreta en css para no tener que usar imágenes y nose si va ser posible hacerla.. Llevo un rato con ello y no hay manera.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que más se acercó...

```css
body{
 background-color: white;
 font-size:16px;

}
.container{
 
 width: 100%;
 height: 4em;
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.container div:nth-child(1){
 margin:0;
 display:inline-block;
 width:15%;
 height: 3.5em;
 background-color: green;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10px;
 
}

.container div:nth-child(2){
 margin:0;
 display:inline-block;
 width:70%;
 height: 3.5em;
 background-color: yellow;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 40% 50%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 40% 50%;
}

.container div:nth-child(3){
 margin:0;
 display:inline-block;
 width:15%;
 height: 3.5em;
 background-color: red;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 40% 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>cunt</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="prueba.css">

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esta persona en SOen lo hizo con SVG https://stackoverflow.com/a/51584142/7023800

Comment: Y esta con CSS aunque se ve un poco "dentada" https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987938/7023800

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil sería utilizar SVG:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 659 80.184">
<path fill="#ead4a2" d="M0,70c0,0,49-7,85-5s164,17,245,15s209-15.719,261-15.359s68,7.768,68,7.768V0H0V70z"/>
</svg>
```